# My image is not responsive when displayed on a mobile phone

Tags: responsive-design, responsive-images

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mifER.jpg) is 500px squared. When offline it is responsive but when online, it is not.

[Link to the page](http://www.4manijewels.com/)

My css

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    #container {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
        <img style="width: 100%; height:100%;" src="img/index_4.png">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you managed to get it to work? If my answer helped you please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the picture always to fill its parent element width but still maintain its responsive height - set it to have a min-width of 100% and give it an auto height. This way, you're letting the browser calculate the scaled dimensions.

```
img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if I write .picture {

  position:absolute; 
 
  left:0; right:0;
 
  top:0; bottom:0;
 
  margin:auto;
 
 min-width: 100%;
 
 height: auto;
 
}
and <div class="picture"><div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="img/index_4.png">
</div></div>
still does not work.

Comment: Hey @NiBe, I updated my answer, let me know if it helps.